# Filename With French Characters Getting changed when sent to web service as multipart form data

Tags: java, rest, encoding, multipartform-data

I have a REST web service in java that takes input as multipart form data:

```
@POST
@Consumes ({MediaProviderJSON.TYPE,MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML,"text/html",MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
@Produces({ text_html, MediaProviderJSON.TYPE })
@Path("/tempUpload")
public Response tempUpload(@Context HttpServletRequest req, @Context HttpServletResponse response)
.
.
// configures upload settings
DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
// sets memory threshold - beyond which files are stored in disk
factory.setSizeThreshold(MEMORY_THRESHOLD);
// sets temporary location to store files
factory.setRepository(new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")));

ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
List<FileItem> formItems = upload.parseRequest(req);
FileItem item = formItems.get(0);
String fileName = item.getName();
System.out.println(fileName);
.
.
.
```

I am trying to upload a file using this HTML:

```
    <html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action= "http://localhost:8080/mywebapp/services/tempUpload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="attachments">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
```

When I upload the file with file name as *français* I get an output on the console as *fran�ais*.

I don't understand whether it is a change in encoding or the name is actually getting corrupted.

Can someone please help here. I need the actual filename on the console.

I thought it was an encoding issue so tried converting the filename using below code:

```
byte[] nameBytes = fileName.getBytes("iso-8859-1");
fileName = new String(nameBytes, "UTF-8");
```

It did not help.

EDIT:

The above HTML is just a sample of my web app. I've my app deployed on different servers. When I call this service from one server, I'm getting correct result while on another server I'm getting the corrupted data. Details of the server are:

server1(correct o/p):

> Request Headers:
> Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>   Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
>   Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
>   Connection:keep-alive
>   Content-Length:443
>   Content-Type:multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary6aYJSRYJByguER4s
>
> Response Headers
>   Connection:Keep-Alive
>   Content-Encoding:gzip
>   Content-Length:142
>   Content-Type:text/html
>   Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
>   Server:nginx/0.5.14
>   Vary:Accept-Encoding

server2(incorrect o/p):

> Request Headers:
> Accept:*/* 
>   Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
>   Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
>   Connection:keep-alive
>   Content-Length:206
>   Content-Type:multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyfnGQAtMhC4buFRS
>
> Content-Type, Accept
>   Connection:Keep-Alive
>   Content-Encoding:gzip
>   Content-Length:152
>   Content-Type:application/json
>   Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=99
>   Server:Apache/2.4.10 (Unix) 
>   Vary:Accept-Encoding

I hope it helps you guys in helping me find a solution.

Comment: It is an encoding issue.

Comment: @Raedwald I agree its an encoding issue. i'm not able to understand where exactly the filename is getting encoded to some other encoding scheme. My HTML page does not specify any encoding scheme explicitely in its meta tag. Also, in my browser's developer tool, I can see that the filename being sent is very much correct.

Answer (score 1):

Do you deploy the application on Tomcat? If so you may declare the character encoding of the context of you application. It should match what You have declared as character encoding on your html page. The example you gave in the question lacks a character encoding declaration.

To change the character encoding of the context of you application edit the META-INF/context.xml in the following fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context URIEncoding="UTF-8" path="">
</Context>
```

If everything is configured properly (the page contains character encoding information, the same character encoding is declared in context.xml) the code fragment You gave above should work just fine:

```
FileItem item = formItems.get(0);
String fileName = item.getName();
```